# Are the methods of derived class facets called from the base class?

Tags: c++, locale

Say I have a setup like this:

```
std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));
stream.imbue(std::locale());
```

When I attempt to call a method of an instance of a facet using `std::use_facet`, will its derived class facet's (i.e a "byname" facet) method actually be called? For example, does this:

```
std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(stream.getloc()).is( /*... */ );
```

do something *conceptually* equivalent to this:

```
std::ctype_byname<char>("C").is( /* ... */ );
```

I figure this is the case because some derived class facets (in this case `std::ctype_byname`) implement the virtual functions of the base class. Am I right to assume this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will be a reference to a  `std::ctype<char>` facet that will be returned. The methods of a `std::ctype` facet (that was not default-constructed on construction of the its locale) will operate based on the locale to which it was installed. Using a byname facet means that you want a specific cultural convention on which to apply its methods that could possibly differ from its locale. It fills the same slot as a base class facet, so `use_facet` won't return a byname facet.